# OpenCart: Create new Product when Inserting new Order - Admin Area

Tags: opencart

In normal flow, OpenCart has to create a product **before** creating an order.

However, my client has a requirement that he wants to create a new product in Order creation form. In my plan, I want to allow the Admin to type the new product's name in "Choose Product:" box. If the product does not exist, it will popup a sub-page, or a box to allow him to insert the price of the product.

Do I have to create a custom Order creation form to serve his needs? If yes, where to start?

[image: Screenshot of Adding Product when Inserting Order]

Comment: You could open the normal *create product* screen in a modal window (e.g. as an iframe, or with many jquery plugins simply by AJAX loading the contents of the request) while you could add some switch to the URL indicating the template to not render the header, footer, columns, etc. - only the main content. Since this should be in iframe submitting the form should only save the product. I would add a button *New product* next to the *Choose product* textfield so that after the product is created admin has to type in the name of new product to select it (to retrieve it's ID for the order form).

Comment: Good idea. Do you know which file does this page belong?

Comment: You should do a request to URL `http://yourstore.com/admin/index.php?route=catalog/product/insert&token=<ACTUAL_SESSION_CSRF_TOKEN>&iframe=1`. The template is `admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl`. Controller is `admin/controller/catalog/product.php`.